# Ubuntu 14.04 Black Stripe in Desktop

Tags: 14.04, display-resolution

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 on two computers for about 9 months.  I have a third computer running Zorin and it works well.  I decided to remove the Zorin and put Ubuntu 14.04 on that computer.  After installing Ubuntu, I have a black vertical stripe running thru my desktop.  If I go to the screen resolution and make a change, the stripe goes away.  If I change the background color the stripe goes away.  When I reboot the system, the stripe is back.  I thought well maybe it was a problem with the onboard video and Ubuntu.  So I installed Xbuntu 14.04.3, same results.  Also the video does not fit the screen very well, some items are off the screen, never had that problem with Zorin.

Update: All screens display correctly.  I found that if I went to the plain background, There is a plain color background, one that fades horizontally and one that fades vertically.  If I choose the vertical fade, it fills in the black vertical stripe.  Then I can go back to the solid color and all is well, works as it should.  If I reboot, I have to go thru the whole process all over again.  Changing resolutions has no bearing, the stripe is in them all.  I read that updating the Intel video driver to the i830 might help and setting the AGP from 1Mb to 8Mb might help.  I set the AGP to the 8Mb setting, no help there. There was a note in the Ubuntu 14.04.3 forum saying the i830 driver was no longer available due to a bug in 14.04.3.  I am thinking this is a Intel video driver problem, but why does it work after messing with the background colors?  Then you lose the fix after reboot.  Could it possibly be a bad CMOS battery?  Thanks!

Computer: Dell Optiplex GX-270 Mid Size, 3Gb Ram, P4 processor, Bios A07, 160Gb HD.  My monitor is a Vizio TV with RGB/HD and resolution is set at 1360x768 16:9.  I use RGB for the computer and it worked fine with Zorin.

Any ideas? (Besides going back to Zorin)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the fix.  I installed a GeForce FX-5200 AGP card and it fixed the
 problem.  Native resolution is 6:9, 1360x768 and no driver installation was required on my part.  I can live with that.  The GeForce video card I got is
the one for dual monitors however, I am only using one monitor and it is the SFF card for a Dell Optiplex GX270.  There are some out here with a single VGA connector.  The card and the DMS-59 cable was under $20, used on eBay.